# Spliting string with integers and charcters into two subarrays

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string ,

```
var a ="abc3bv5";
```

i have to split this string into two arrays one array should contain all the integers in the string and one should contain the characters present in the string.

Comment: You need this in Javascript?

Comment: `var a1 = a.match(/\d/g), b = a.match(/\D/g);`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string and then filter the ones which you require:

```js
var a = "abc3bv5";
var spl = a.split('');
var letters = spl.filter(char => /[a-z]/i.test(char));
var numbers = spl.filter(char => /[0-9]/.test(char));

console.log(letters);
console.log(numbers);

// or better
var result = {
  numbers: [],
  letters: []
};

spl.forEach(char => {
  if (/[a-z]/i.test(char)) {
    result.letters.push(char);
  } else if (/[0-9]/.test(char)) {
    result.numbers.push(char);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. I hope it will help-

```
var a ="abc3bv5";
var num = [];
var str = [];
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(a[i]))){
      num.push(a[i]);
   } else {
      str.push(a[i]);
   }
}

console.log(num);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a functional/immutable method:

```
const letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function getNumbersAndLettersFromString(stringInput) {
    const chars = string.split('');

    chars.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (letters.includes(curr)) {
            return {
                ...acc,
                letters: [
                    ....acc.letters,
                    curr,
                ]
            };
        }

        if (numbers.includes(curr)) {
            return {
                ...acc,
                numbers: [
                    ....acc.numbers,
                    curr,
                ]
            };   
        }
    }, {letters: [], numbers: []})
}
```